# El ciclo for en javascript,¿puede alterar variables?

Tags: javascript, variables, loops, ciclos

Tengo una duda,encontré el siguiente código de calcular el número factorial de un número entero,pero estoy haciendo mi corrida de escritorio y no logro comprender el código por que se supone que en el proceso del factorial se va multiplicando por todos los números que estén dados antes del numero a calcular ,y la única respuesta que encuentro al siguiente código es que en la variable "resultado" vaya almacenando el valor de la multiplicación y ese lo multiplique por "i" hasta 5 y ahí termina el ciclo,pero no estoy seguro si lo que pienso es correcto,les dejo el código y espero puedan auxiliar a este neófito.

```
var numero = prompt("Introduce un número y se mostrará su factorial");
var resultado = 1;

for(var i=1; i<=numero; i++) {
  resultado *= i;
}
alert(resultado);
```

Comment: Cierto; "resultado" al final del proceso tiene el valor a retornar (que se muestra en el alert); y sí, el "for" afecta variables como cualquier ciclo en cualquier lenguaje de programación (bueno al menos de los que he usado su comportamiento con las variables han sido idénticos)

Comment: Ok entonces,entonces cuando yo declare una variable y quiera hacer una operación de este tipo,la variable ira cambiando conforme a las iteraciones del bucle?,y el valor que tiene en este caso "resultado" el cual es "1",ira cambiando?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tal como dijiste, es la multiplicación de los números que le anteceden.

Ej:

```
5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

Pero es exactamente lo mismo que hacer la multiplicacion al reves

```
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 5!
```

Por tanto

```
var numero = prompt("Introduce un número y se mostrará su factorial");
var resultado = 1;

for(var i=1; i<=numero; i++) {
  resultado *= i;
}
alert(resultado);
```

Y teniendo como acotacion esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se entiende que lo que esta multiplicando es desde 1 hasta n, con el resultado. Vale decir:

```
resultado = 1 * resultado;

resultado = 2 * resultado;

resultado = 3 * resultado;

resultado = 4 * resultado;

hasta. . .

resultado = n * resultado;
```

Y como bien dijiste se iba guardando en la variable resultado, entonces una vez terminado el ciclo, se presenta en un alert.

Espero que se entienda el concepto. Saludos!!!

Comment: Ya lo entendi,ahora a practicar!!!por cierto algun libro donde expliquen las propiedades de los bucles y sentencias?

Comment: No es un libro, pero te ayudara un buen poco. https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_PHP/Bucles